# How to get the variable value after matching with preg_match

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
$str = "nbvmxnbvn Shopify.shop=gfkhfhkd";
preg_match('/Shopify.shop=/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

I'm getting the output after print_r as `Shopify.shop=` but I want `gfkhfhkd` as the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your regex slightly so that it can capture the proper substring you're looking for.

```
preg_match('/Shopify.shop=(.*)/',$str,$matches);
echo $matches[1];   //gfkhfhkd
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/718825)**

Comment: E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined offset: 1

Comment: yup sorry my mistak / was extra at first time

Comment: but also i want to stop the match on ";" occrance

Comment: Simple! do `/Shopify.shop=(.*);/`

Comment: Have some rest before you continue :)

Comment: Hanky thanks for the help the issue got resolved '/Shopify.shop =(.*)\;/'  this resolved it

Answer (score 0):

```
$matches = preg_grep('/Shopify.shop=(.*)/', $str);
print_r ($matches);
```